# asking about my gpu information using opencl

Tags: opencl, gpu

can any one help me how can find this information about my platform 
i can find it using getdeviceinfo . there are any method for that or complete code to fetch all this info

```
 Number of platforms:                 1
 Platform Profile:              FULL_PROFILE
 Platform Version:              OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (938.2)
 Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
 Platform Vendor:               Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
 Platform Extensions:               cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback       cl_amd_offline_devices


 Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
 Number of devices:               4
 Device Type:                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
 Device ID:                     4098
 Board name:                    AMD Radeon HD 6550D
 Device Topology:               PCI[ B#0, D#1, F#0 ]
 Max compute units:                 5
 Max work items dimensions:             3
 Max work items[0]:               256
 Max work items[1]:               256
 Max work items[2]:               256
 Max work group size:               256
 Preferred vector width char:           16
 Preferred vector width short:          8
 Preferred vector width int:            4
 Preferred vector width long:           2
 Preferred vector width float:          4
 Preferred vector width double:         0
 Native vector width char:          16
 Native vector width short:             8
 Native vector width int:           4
 Native vector width long:          2
 Native vector width float:             4
 Native vector width double:            0
 Max clock frequency:               0Mhz
 Address bits:                  32
 Max memory allocation:             536870912
 Image support:                 Yes
 Max number of images read arguments:       128
 Max number of images write arguments:      8
 Max image 2D width:                8192
 Max image 2D height:               8192
 Max image 3D width:                2048
 Max image 3D height:               2048
 Max image 3D depth:                2048
 Max samplers within kernel:            16
 Max size of kernel argument:           1024
 Alignment (bits) of base address:      2048
 Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:    128
 Single precision floating point capability
 Denorms:                     No
 Quiet NaNs:                  Yes
 Round to nearest even:           Yes
 Round to zero:               Yes
 Round to +ve and infinity:           Yes
 IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:         Yes
 Cache type:                    None
 Cache line size:               0
 Cache size:                    0
 Global memory size:                536870912
 Constant buffer size:              65536
 Max number of constant args:           8
 Local memory type:                 Scratchpad
 Local memory size:                 32768
 Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:     64
 Error correction support:          0
 Unified memory for Host and Device:        1
 Profiling timer resolution:            1
 Device endianess:              Little
 Available:                     Yes
 Compiler available:                Yes
 Execution capabilities:                
 Execute OpenCL kernels:          Yes
 Execute native function:             No
 Queue properties:              
 Out-of-Order:                No
 Profiling :                  Yes
 Platform ID:                   0x7f07dc0c6ce0
 Name:                      BeaverCreek
 Vendor:                    Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
 Device OpenCL C version:           OpenCL C 1.2 
 Driver version:                CAL 1.4.1741
 Profile:                   FULL_PROFILE
 Version:                   OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (938.2)
 Extensions:                    cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store   cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_ext_atomic_counters_32 cl_amd_device_attribute_query cl_amd_vec3      cl_amd_printf cl_amd_media_ops cl_amd_popcnt
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Yes, you can find all of this information using `clGetDeviceInfo()`. If you want example code that will actually produce all of the above, then you can usually find a 'device info' sample in most OpenCL SDKs.

Comment: I don't understand, you are using a free tool to dump that information (clinfo), but you are asking for a method to do it. Why not take the code of the free tool instead? For me the question is trivial, it is answered by itself.

Comment: thanks for replay . that result not for me i want any tool or program to give me same info. i know about clgetdeviceinfo but can i find complete opencl program for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an app called **GPU Caps viewer** which will show the capabilities of all the OpenCL devices available in your system.

http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/

Answer (score 3):

Take at look at the [Intel OpenCL SDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk)

There's an app they provide called "Basic Capabilities" that lists most of what you're looking for.  Each app even comes with a PDF users guide.  Near the back the users guide has a section called "Controlling the Sample" which lists command-line options for the app.

One of the command line options is `<PLATFORM>`. The apps default to looking for "Intel" hardware but I've specified the platform as "NVidia" and things worked for me.